# How to generate Diffie-Hellman parameters in golang

Tags: go, diffie-hellman

Is there a Golang equivalent to the following openssl command?

`openssl dhparam -out dh.pem 2048`

I would like to be able to generate Diffie-Hellman parameters with golang and not need to invoke openssl.

Comment: You may as well just exec.Command it in a goroutine. This process may take several minutes, perhaps even an hour on a slow system. And it's not possible to predict how long it runs.

Comment: I'm wondering if meanwhile this is possible to be done in pure Go: the use case of managing a certificate authority (e.g. for OpenVPN) without the need for forking `openssl`  seems legit.